# Serialisation/deserialisation for sealed traits with Upickle

Tags: scala, scala.js, upickle

I am trying to call a webservice from my play server I am using upickle for serialisation/deserialisation . My problem I have a sealed trait as

```
sealed trait RequestContent {
}
case class CreateUserRequest (email: String, password: String,jsonBlob: Map[String, String], createBTCWallet: Boolean) extends RequestContent
```

And when I try using `upickle.default.write` as

```
val userRequest = CreateUserRequest("email","pw",Map("name" -> "name", true))
write(userRequest)
```

it gives an extra key for `$type`. Is there a way to get the data to post without type in upickle??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a sealed trait hierarchy, uPickle needs an additional `$type` field to be able to deserialize, since it needs to know which subclass to instantiate.

So the presence of this extra key is perfectly normal and necessary. It is not possible to remove it, as that would prevent deserialization from working.

Comment: If i am getting this right then in that case i have no way to use upickle to post data to remote web service.

Comment: Not by using the default picklers/unpicklers for sealed traits. uPickle was not designed for this use case, but rather for a use case where uPickle is also use to deserialize on the other side. You could however write a [custom pickler](http://lihaoyi.github.io/upickle-pprint/upickle/#CustomPicklers) for your sealed trait, that would do exactly what you want.